# What is a compressor cascade?

Tags: jet-engine, compressor, blade

Is a compressor cascade just the representation of the blade ring of an actual turbomachine? What is the difference between linear cascade and annular cascade? A diagram or a reference would be great.

Comment: In mechanics, a cascade is the same equipment put in series, the output of one being the input of the following one. You may precise why you think this is different for compressors so that answer can focus on your interrogation instead of the general mechanical concept.

Comment: A compressor cascade usually refers to a non-rotating test setup to assess blade performance.